# Swifty JSON on swift can't get data

Tags: ios, iphone, json, swift, swift2

I have this code but the problem is that I can't get the exact value instead it will give me a null value when i test in in `NSLog`

```
func parseJSON() {

    let path: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("vehicles", ofType: "json") as String!
    let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) as NSData!
    let readableJSON = JSON(data: jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)

    let Makes = readableJSON["Make"]
    NSLog("\(Makes)")


}
```

and I have the sample JSON object here:

```
[
{
 "id": "56c3fe547816d74d1c34fcaf",
 "IDVehicle": "323405",
 "IDCustomer": "77",
  "Make": "AUDI",
 "Model": "A4"
},
{
"id": "56c3fe547816d74d1c34fe2a",
"IDVehicle": "248599",
"IDCustomer": "432307",
"Make": "MAZDA",
"Model": "6"
}
]
```

**NOTE:** I'm using the SwiftyJSON from github thanks

Comment: Your JSON is an array of dictionaries so you need to provide which item of  an array you want to read...
Ex: readableJSON[0]["Make"]

Comment: with above code you will get dictionary stored at array index 0

Comment: @vivektakrani thank you sir. but how can i display them all? like how to display all Make? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using for loop...

With Index

```
for (index, element) in enumerate(readableJSON) {
    println("Item \(index): \(element["Make"])")
}
```

or without index

```
for element in readableJSON{
   print("element["Make"]")
}
```

But make sure that readableJSON is an array.